# Почему при импорте второго скрипта, происходит выполнение программы?

Tags: python

Есть два простейших скрипта prover.py:

```
import gsmgps

#gsmgps.hello()
```

И gsmgps.py:

```
print("hello")
```

Почему при запуске скрипта prover.py он заходит во второй скрипт и выводит print? Ведь файл prover.py закомментирован и я явно не указываю ему выводить что-либо из второго файла?

Comment: При импорте модуля Python выполняет весь код в нём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что и при импорте код в скрипте выполняется.

Чтобы не было выполнения кода, при импорте, оберните в условие такой код, например:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello")
```

Тогда, только при запуске код в `if __name__ == "__main__":` будет выполняться

---

**PS.**

А в случае импортирования файла, у него в `__name__` будет его имя без расширения.

Проверить просто:

```
print(__name__)
```

**PPS.**

Это, кст, полезно для скриптов, из которых можно получить переменные/функции/классы и запускать их как самостоятельные единицы.

Например, у нас есть модуль для математических выражений и в нем же мы вызываем их, а чтобы код вызова не выполнился при импортировании обернули в `if __name__ == "__main__"`, **calc.py**:

```
def calc(text):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calc("2+2*2"))
    ...
```

И есть другой модуль, что импортирует первый для своих нужд, **main.py**:

```
from calc import calc

print(calc("3**9+1"))
```